# Produce two shiny widgets from the same uiOutput() at the same time

Tags: r, shiny

I have the shiny dashboard below in which I select from the `pickerInput()` `"Select Database/s"` if I will display the values of either `Sepal.Length` if only this is selected or `Sepal.Width` if only this is selected or both if both selected. Is it possible to achieve it inside the same `uiOutput("fnamesid")` and without having to use 2 different `uiOutput()`?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
ui <- dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(title = "My dashboard"),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
        uiOutput("dbs"),
        uiOutput("fnamesid")
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(

    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$dbs<-renderUI({

            pickerInput("DB", "Select Database/s", 
                        choices = c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width"), 
                        multiple = T,options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                        selected = "Sepal.Length")

    })
    output$fnamesid<-renderUI({

            if("Sepal.Length"%in% input$DB){
                pickerInput("sn", "Select sn_ID for x-axis", 
                            choices = unique(iris$Sepal.Length), 
                            multiple = T,options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                            selected = head(unique(iris$Sepal.Length)))

            }
        else if("Sepal.Width"%in% input$DB){
            pickerInput("sn2", "Select sn_ID for x-axis", 
                        choices = unique(iris$Sepal.Width), 
                        multiple = T,options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                        selected = head(unique(iris$Sepal.Width)))

        }
        else if("Sepal.Length"%in% input$DB&"Sepal.Width"%in% input$DB){
            pickerInput("sn", "Select sn_ID for x-axis", 
                        choices = unique(iris$Sepal.Length), 
                        multiple = T,options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                        selected = head(unique(iris$Sepal.Length)))


            pickerInput("sn2", "Select sn_ID for x-axis", 
                        choices = unique(iris$Sepal.Width), 
                        multiple = T,options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                        selected = head(unique(iris$Sepal.Width)))

        }



    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that if both options are selected in `input$DB`, then the condition of the first `if ()` statement is `TRUE` and that is the element of your `if-then-else` chain that gets executed.  So, the first thing to do is to move the "both are selected" element of the chain to the top and adjust your logic accordingly.

Second, to return two (or more) UI elements from the same call to `renderUI()`, wrap them in a `tagList()`.  Here's a version of your `output$fnamesid` that works for me:

```
  output$fnamesid<-renderUI({
    if ("Sepal.Length" %in% input$DB & "Sepal.Width" %in% input$DB){
      tagList(
        pickerInput("sn", "Select sn_ID for x-axis", 
                  choices = unique(iris$Sepal.Length), 
                  multiple = T,options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                  selected = head(unique(iris$Sepal.Length))),
        pickerInput("sn2", "Select sn_ID for x-axis", 
                  choices = unique(iris$Sepal.Width), 
                  multiple = T,options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                  selected = head(unique(iris$Sepal.Width)))
      )
    }
    else if("Sepal.Length"%in% input$DB){
      pickerInput("sn", "Select sn_ID for x-axis", 
                  choices = unique(iris$Sepal.Length), 
                  multiple = T,options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                  selected = head(unique(iris$Sepal.Length)))
    }
    else if("Sepal.Width"%in% input$DB){
      pickerInput("sn2", "Select sn_ID for x-axis", 
                  choices = unique(iris$Sepal.Width), 
                  multiple = T,options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                  selected = head(unique(iris$Sepal.Width)))      
    }
```

Notice the comma between the two `pickerInput`s in the `tagList`.  It's important! ;)